# Rename obfuscated names with .NET Reflector?

Tags: tools, obfuscation, .net, c#

I have some obfuscated C# .NET code I want to analyze.

[image: obfuscated C# code]

Is it possible to rename those obfuscated symbols? So I can more easily track them? Like IDA Pro can work with renaming functions and so forth.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some plugins like [reflexil](http://reflexil.net/) provide this functionality.

Comment: You should probably comment on how it does it and what a result might look like.